# ionic2 - The generate command is only available for projects that use ionic-angular >= 3.0.0

Tags: angular, ionic2

When I generate a project page, error coming, but still can generate this page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It clearly says on the doc. If you need to use latest generators then you must update the project to `ionic-angular >= 3.0.0`. Latest generators have tight coupling with the `ionic-angular` `module`.

**Note:** If you don't like to update latest then just create your components manually. No restrictions for that :)

> Generate pipes, components, pages, directives, providers, and tabs
> (ionic-angular >= 3.0.0)

You can read more about [it on the doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/).

### Update

If you need to update then you have to [do this changes](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json) on your `package.json` file.

See also [this video upgrade guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQJMUOznMrA). This is for Ionic 3, but the concept is the same.

[Release notes](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases) are here.

Comment: Thanks, so what should I do if I want to update the project to ionic-angular >= 3.0.0, Is it will make my project not working?

Comment: Please see the **Note** and **Update** sections.Yes, It has breaking changes.So you need to solve those ones by one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try later

Comment: Ok sure.Good Luck! :)